# How to make a Model Class Within Model Class (Flutter / Dart)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, model

I am trying to make a multivendor app with Flutter.
The problem I am facing right now is how can I make a model class within a Model class:

**Example:**

```dart
class ProductModel {
String? name;
double? price;
String? imgUrl;
double? weight;

ProductModel();

ProductMode.fromSnapShot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
name = snapshot['name'];
price= snapshot['price'];
imgUrl= snapshot['imgUrl'];
weight= snapshot['weight'];
}
}
```

I have already retrieved all the products from `Firestore`:

```dart
class VendorModel{
String? name;
String? imgUrl;
DateTime? opensAt;
DateTime? closesAt;


VendorModel();

VendorModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
name = snapshot['name'];
imgUrl= snapshot['imgUrl'];
opensAt= DateTime.tryParse(snapshot['opensAt'].toString());
closesAt= DateTime.tryParse(snapshot['closesAt'].toString());
}
}
```

**I have also retrieved all the vendors from Firestore:**

Here is What I am trying to do:
I would like to add the products I fetched from `Firestore` to their respective vendors using this model. But I don't know how to make this if my data is from `Firestore`.

```dart
class VendorWithProductsModel{
VendorModel vendor;
List<ProductModel> products;

VendorWithProductsModel();
(I AM STUCK HERE)
}
```

Here is a Snippet of my `Firestore` code in retrieving products and vendors:

```dart
VendorModel _vendor = VendorModel();
List<VendorModel> _allVendors = [];

Future<VendorModel> getCertainVendor(docId) async{
    await vendor.doc(docId).get().then((value){
      _vendor = VendorModel.fromSnapshot(value);
    });
    return _vendor;
  }
Future<List<VendorModel>> getAllVendors() async{
    await vendor.get().then((value){
      _allVendors.add(VendorModel.fromSnapshot(value));
    });
    return _allVendors;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your product model, you need something like `vendorId`, where you can know which product belongs to which vendor.
- After fetching all your products and vendors. Use both list, and loop through them, this is pseudo code for example:

```
List<VendorWithProductsModel> doMagic (List<ProductModel> productList, List<VendorModel> vendorList) {

  List<VendorWithProductsModel> vendorsWithProducts =[];
  vendorList.forEach((vendor){ 
    VendorWithProductsModel _vendorAndProduct = VendorWithProductsModel();
    _vendorAndProduct.vendor = vendor;
    _vendorAndProduct.products =[];
    _vendorAndProduct.products = productList.where((e)=> e.vendorId == vendor.id).toList();
    vendorsWithProducts.add(_vendorAndProduct);
  });

 return vendorsWithProducts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply..but i am having an error..

return _vendorAndProduct;
i am having errors here.. "Undefined name '_vendorAndProduct'."

Comment: i finally got it..Thank you so much..
i just changed `return _vendorAndProduct;` to `return vendorsWithProducts;`

Comment: You're most welcome, I modified it as well in the answer. Happy coding :-)